# Smart Contract UI Docs or Tutorial

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Is there documentation on how to interact with an Ink smart contract via ReactJS and polkadot.js or capi?
Using the metadata that is generated from the smart contract.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this cool tutorial that shows how to interact using PolkadotJS apps and React!

- https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/build-polkadot-amm-using-ink

Comment: Pretty in depth tutorial. that is awesome. One question. Does the metadata.json provide types for Typescript for the objects that the smart contract uses in its messages? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our new project https://github.com/Supercolony-net/typechain-polkadot, it is still in development, but you can also use the beta versions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/typechain

Comment: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate is a great place to surface things like this :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't found it already, the polkadot.js docs have a section on contracts where you can learn how to [read values](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read) and [execute transactions](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.tx)